# Azure Derived Column - Create another column from the value of a column based on the value of another column

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a table something like:

| Country | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | LastKnownYear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2019 |
| Germany | 4 | 5 | 6 | 2018 |
| Italy | 7 | 8 | 9 | 2020 |

I want to add another column "latestKnownValue"

| Country | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | LastKnownYear | latestKnownValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2019 | 2 |
| Germany | 4 | 5 | 6 | 2018 | 4 |
| Italy | 7 | 8 | 9 | 2020 | 9 |

I've simplified the example, while I'm working with years, the reality of the table is that there are many years (all as columns) in the source table.

How can I do this using the "Derived Column" activity in Azure. Or is there another way of doing this in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

An even much simpler example in ADF data flow derived column:

Create a new column called 'latestKnownValue' and use this expression:

toInteger(byName('LastKnownYear'))

Answer (score -1):

A simple T-SQL `CASE` statement should suffice:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp;

CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    Country         VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    [2018]          INT NOT NULL,
    [2019]          INT NOT NULL,
    [2020]          INT NOT NULL,
    LastKnownYear   INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT 'Spain', 1,  2,  3,  2019
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Germany',   4,  5,  6,  2018
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Italy', 7,  8,  9,  2020;


SELECT *,
    CASE LastKnownYear
        WHEN '2018' THEN [2018]
        WHEN '2019' THEN [2019]
        WHEN '2020' THEN [2020]
        ELSE NULL
    END AS latestKnownValue--,
    --CHOOSE ( LastKnownYear - 2017, [2018], [2019], [2020] ) AS chooseExample

FROM #tmp;
  

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM #tmp
UNPIVOT ( xvalue for xyear In ( [2018], [2019], [2020] ) ) upvt
)
SELECT 
    t.Country, t.[2018], t.[2019], t.[2020], t.LastKnownYear, 
    c.xvalue AS lastKnownValue
FROM #tmp t
    INNER JOIN cte c ON t.Country = c.Country
        AND t.LastKnownYear = c.xyear;
```

You will not have access to `CHOOSE` in Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL pools just now but it's really the same thing, syntactic sugar.  Another alternative would be to `UNPIVOT` your columns then join as per my last example.

Comment: Any update on this?  If your table is already in a dedicated SQL pool then it would make sense to use T-SQL to update it.  If you are loading the file then consider Mapping Data Flows as per Mark's answer.